# FrameLayout above a viewPager in fragment the onTouch Event has bean intercepted

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, ontouch

a fragment has two views a FrameLayout  contains some children views ,below the FrameLayout there has a viewPager .
 I want to replace the fragment when there has an action like ACTION_MOVE on FrameLayout ,so I add a onTouchListener on FrameLayout but it never work,viewPager works well,and also the FrameLayout's children views has onClick event

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.hall_gift, container,
            false);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.fans_body_title);
    frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Log.i(TAG,"ACTION DOWN");
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: By "framlayout", you mean `FrameLayout`, right?

Comment: yes!! sorry for spelling erros!!

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the FrameLayout and override its onInterceptTouchEvent() to intercept the touch events from child view. Then, use your self-defined FrameLayout instead of the previous FrameLayout.

Plz refer to this document:
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#intercept

Here is a code snippet:

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

   @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    /*
     * This method determines whether we want to intercept the motion.
     * If we return true, onTouchEvent will be called.
     */

           final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);    
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    if(meet your condition){
                        return true;
                    }
                }

            }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I kown what you said.3Q

Comment: yes !The frameLayout does not intercept even default,when we want it's ontouch work we need intercept ourself

Comment: @Sunday Since my answer works, you can accept it, in case it can help others who has the same problem. And I can also gain reputation as a reward. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you give

```
  android:clickable="true"
```

to your framelayout
it does not allow touch to your viewpager